# Mission Control - Multiple Screens, Zoom, Keeping One Screen Static

Tags: display, mission-control, zoom, dual-screen

Goal:
I need Mission Control to give me desktop options on one screen at a time. How can I do this? (Desktop & Dock > Displays Have Separate Spaces doesn't control this.)

---

I am in a creative field and on Zoom. We draw on the screen to share ideas and then screenshot the drawings, esp drawings from our director. If I want to switch from Zoom to the desktop that has an image I have pulled up to show during the call, or because someone asks to see a particular email, Mission Control gives me desktop options on both my primary and secondary monitor at the same time - Mission Control jumps out of everything on both screens and shows me all the options. And when this happens, all the drawings on the screen are erased. And I also give everyone a view of everything else I have running on my computer. It is quite literally Everything Everywhere All At Once.

Answer (score 2):

> I need Mission Control to give me desktop options on one screen at a time.

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Mission Control, by design, gives a “birds eye view” of all your open applications and spaces.  By design, you can move applications to/from spaces even on different screens (monitors).  As such, it needs to ooen up on every screen.

As a workaround, try staging the spaces on your selected monitor and using <kbd>^ Control</kbd>  <kbd>→</kbd>  or  <kbd>←</kbd>  to switch between spaces without activating Mission Control.

Comment: Ctrl, by default, rather than Cmd. Otherwise, exactly what I would have said.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin.  Sometimes i confuse and forget shortcuts when using a virtual keyboard!  The finger memory doesn’t seem to connect to my actual memory sometimes!